# How to update date field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I have data in my Elastic index as below :

Indexed data as:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}'
```

Mapping obtained using

> curl -XGET localhost:9200/twitter
>
> {"twitter":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"tweet":{"properties":{"message":{"type":"string"},"post_date":{"type":"date","format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"},"user":{"type":"string"}}}},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1456739938440","number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"DwhS57l1TsKQFyzY23LSiQ","version":{"created":"2020099"}}},"warmers":{}}}

Now if I am modifying user as below I am able to do the same:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1/_update' -d '{
   "script" : "ctx._source.user=new_user",
   "params" : {
      "new_user" : "search"
   }
}'
```

But when I tried modifying the date fields as below it is giving an exception :

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1/_update' -d '{
   "script" : "ctx._source.post_date='new-date'",
   "params" : {
      "new-date" : "2016-02-02T16:12:23"
   }
}'
```

Exception received is :

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":"[Anomaly][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"failed
>   to execute
>   script","caused_by":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"Failed to
>   compile inline script [ctx._source.post_date=new-date] using lang
>   [groovy]","caused_by":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"failed to
>   compile groovy
>   script","caused_by":{"type":"multiple_compilation_errors_exception","reason":"startup failed:\ne90a551666b36d90e4fc5b08d04250da5c4d552d: 1: unexpected
>   token: - @ line 1, column 26.\n   ctx._source.post_date=new-date\n
>   ^\n\n1 error\n"}}}}

Now can anyone let me know how I can handle the same.

~Prashant

Comment: Can you share your mapping using `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`?

Comment: which exception is it ? To ask an obvious question, are you sure you are not writing `last-login` or `new-login` ?

Comment: Where's the `-` in the above example?

Comment: @JérémieB : Apologize for the typo , yes in my actual problem we have last-login and new-login.. Is that a problem , but I have also tried with new_login , so there as well it gave an exception as - is present in date value?

Comment: @Val : mapping is like for last-login : type : date , format : date_time_no_millis

Comment: @tim_yates : "-" is present in date value... "12-10-2016T12:34:56"

Comment: Yeah, but that's a string...

Comment: Yes , still its not working..

Comment: @tim_yates : 
This is the docs I indexed:

Comment: @tim_yates : Can you check the question post as I have revamped with actual data scenario

Comment: @Val Can you check the question post as I have revamped with actual data scenario

Answer (score 2):

```
POST your_index_name/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
    "script" : {
      "source": "ctx._source.publishedDate=new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').parse('2021-05-07')",
      "lang": "painless"  
    }
}
```

- publishedDate - the name of your date field.
- Your_index_name the name of you index

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy (or in Java), an identifier can't contain a '-'. If you write

```
ctx._source.last-login = new-login
```

Groovy (and java!) parses this into :

```
(ctx._source.last)-(login) = (new)-(login)
```

You should quote these properties :

```
ctx._source.'last-login' = 'new-login'
```

Comment: Yes, even I tried with the same and when i am adding a quotes Elastic goes on to hang and never returns back, and need to manually kill the service to make it work

Comment: this behavior is probably not related to this expression : with your error, ElasticSearch fail at the beginning and do nothing.

Comment: Yes, so how can we find like where exactly elasticsearch failed.. and script is conditional and will execute if condition satisfies.

Comment: You should probably ask another question : this one was about a Groovy expression. There isn't any context here to help you with a failure in ES (The request you do ? The mapping ? Logs in ES ? A reproductible test ?)

Comment: But the exception it gave was related to groovy so though of asking in Groovy forum, BTW I will update the question with real time data and fields along with mapping so that if you can get something form the same.

Comment: "But the exception it gave was related to groovy". Yes, and fixed by this answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104844/discussion-between-prashant-agrawal-and-jeremie-b).

Comment: Can you check the question post as I have revamped with actual data scenario

Comment: I read it but didnt get it... what answer you mean to refer in this

Comment: The code you wrote in your description is not the code you are executing : `ctx._source.post_date=new-date` : You don't have quote around `new-date`

Comment: "script" : "ctx._source.post_date='new-date'",
here new-date has the quote ... still same error

Comment: So do you have any idea for the same as quote was added while running the script